# One excel query for multiple data tables

Tags: excel

I have a sql table with 3 product keys - Type, Style, Machine
I can query all the data I need with select * from dbo.tablename
I want to split this data into smaller tables, one for each machine
I currently have 7 queries in excel (Get Data -> From Database -> From SQL Server Database)- "select * from dbo.tablename where machine = '123'" but I am wondering if there is a way to just have 1 "select * from dbo.tablename" in excel, and with that datatable in excel split it into smaller tables

Comment: Use Group By - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm

Comment: Have one sheet "data" with all data; "tblData".  Then create per machine a new sheet.
Use the new `FILTER`-function (if you are on Excel 365) to display the data for the the specific machine.